# resteasy + tomcat servlet container 3.0 + guice not working

Tags: tomcat7, guice, resteasy

I am trying to get resteasy 3.0.19, guice 4.0, and tomcat 7.0.73 working together, and I am trying to get something other than a 404 response. To troubleshoot, I just tried to get the guice-hello example to work, slightly modified. On startup, I see that the `HelloModule` and `HelloResource` are picked up and registered.

```
23:09:29.875 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.i18n - RESTEASY011005: found module: org.jboss.resteasy.examples.guice.hello.HelloModule
23:09:30.169 [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.i18n - RESTEASY011020: registering factory for org.jboss.resteasy.examples.guice.hello.HelloResource
[2016-12-08 11:09:30,250] Artifact Gradle : abbvie.ir.pikm : people.service.war (exploded): Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-12-08 11:09:30,250] Artifact Gradle : abbvie.ir.pikm : people.service.war (exploded): Deploy took 3,172 milliseconds
```

However, when I try to access http://localhost:8080/people.service/hello/test, I get a 404 page from tomcat. Just one other thing to note, if I access http://localhost:8080/garbage, I also get a 404 status back, but I do not get a 404 status page, just a blank one.

As this is a 3.0 servlet container, I am not defining any dispatcher servlet in my web.xml. It just looks like:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>People Service</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.jboss.resteasy.examples.guice.hello.HelloModule
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

All the other classes are just the default ones from the guice-hello example, i.e. HelloModule, HelloResource, Greeter, and DefaultGreeter. It looks to me like the default dispatcher is not handling the requests as defined. Any ideas on troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

Stepping through the resteasy code, I found the issue was that in the `ResteastServletInitializer`, which is used for servlet 3.0 containers, if there is no `Application` class defined, then it skips configuration of the `HttpServlet30Dispatcher`. There is a `handleNoApplicationClass` method, but it appears incomplete at this point in time.

The solution was to define the following class:

```
package abbvie.ir.pikm.people.service;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class PeopleServiceApplication extends Application {
}
```